# Include folder in Gradle artifact

Tags: gradle

Im sure this is amazingly simple but its been a long day and the Gradle docs frustrate me at the best of times (I have looked).

I want to include a folder (`libs`) inside a predefinined artifact (`bundleRelease`).

This happens to be on android (aar build) and inside a `maven-publish` block like

```
...
releaseJar(MavenPublication) {
            ...

            artifact bundleRelease
}
...
```

using gradle 2.3.

Thanks for any help here :)

EDIT: answered here [Include /libs/ folder in aar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33243567/include-libs-folder-in-aar)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want for the syntax but if you want the `jar` files in the root of the `aar`

```
android {
    ...
    sourceSets {
        main {
            resources.includes = [ '**/libs/*.jar' ]        
    }
}
```

If you want the entire folder included then I think this should be what you want

```
android {
    ...
    sourceSets {
        main {
            resources.includes = [ 'pathTo/libs' ]        
    }
}
```

All that said you probably don't want to package the libs with the `aar` because if you publish to somewhere like `jcenter` or `mavenCentral` then the maven artifact when uploaded will create a `pom` file that will note its dependencies and gradle will transparently import them for your lib.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, will play with this 2moro. I specifically do want to bundle the libs with the aar as this specific aar needs to distributed with private libs.

Comment: nope none of the above works - this is driving me nuts! Tried with `**/libs/*.jar` and every `<pathTo>/libs` I could think of...