# Include /libs/ folder in aar

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

Feel like Im going mad here - this must be so simple!

I have an android aar which I have built from `gradle assembleRelease` and also using the `maven-publish` plugin. I thought that /libs/ was included by default but evidently not.

Android tools site shows its an optional include

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/aar-format

but for the life of me I don't see where this is configured.

I have asked a related Q [Include folder in Gradle artifact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33243370/include-folder-in-gradle-artifact) but I dont see this as a duplicate as thats a generic gradle question really whereas this is aar specific and may be solved outside of gradle.

Edit I have also asked on the [Gradle forum](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/adding-libs-folder-to-android-aar-release/12334)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The aar packages local libraries in `libs/` so you need to have local jar dependencies.

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
}
```

Comment: Thats absolutely fantastic thanks. I had tried a few subtle variations of `compile fileTree...` approaches as suggested elsewhere (e.g. https://discuss.gradle.org/t/adding-libs-folder-to-android-aar-release/12334 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33243370/include-folder-in-gradle-artifact) without success - but this one works! I have also been using `compile(name:'<libname>-x.y.z')` to consume versioned _local_ (/libs/ based) dependencies but this also did not place anything in the compiled aar. Many many thanks! This has been driving me mad (silly I know as so simple...)

Comment: A related but slightly different question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33277221/android-library-project-depending-on-other-library-projects if you get a mo :)

Comment: Is this still the case? I tried several approaches and still can't get the jar included in the final aar

Comment: I had related problem - needed to include `libs` with jars inside of my AAR. Here is the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53215936/3313614

Answer (score 1):

When the `maven` plugin runs `uploadArchives` then it will create a `pom` file that tells `maven` or `gradle` what dependencies your `aar` needs.  Gradle will handle downloading the `jar` files and placing them in your class path for the build.

I commented on your other question as well

*reference: https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies

*=gradle is backed by maven for dependency management so artifacts available to maven are also available to gradle and vice versa

Comment: thanks for the answer and have commented on other answer too - I specifically want to include the /libs/ folder in this case as the lib jars wont be available via a remote maven repo - otherwise I wouldve gone that route :)