# How to include JAR dependency into an AAR library

Tags: java, android, gradle, jar, aar

**Summary:**

I have an AAR file that depends on a JAR file, when I build the AAR project, it doesn't contain the JAR code.

**Details:**

I have a Java SDK library project that contains code that we use for Java web projects and such, this library is created using `Gradle` and resides in an internal nexus server (as a JAR).

The goal is to provide an "Android configured" version of this JAR library through an AAR library that multiple Android Applications can use and minimize the effort (and boilerplate code) to implement it. This AAR file is also uploaded to the nexus server to be used by the Android Application projects.

**My AAR project includes a gradle dependency for my Java SDK library (the JAR) but when built, the AAR doesn't include any classes from it.**

**Code:**

This is the Java SDK project's gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

//noinspection GroovyUnusedAssignment
sourceCompatibility = 1.7
version = '1.1.1'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

jar {
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    testCompile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-web:3.1.1.RELEASE'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
}
```

This is the gradle file for my AAR Project, note that I removed the Maven repository declarations to my nexus server from it. I guess it shouldn't matter for the sake of this question.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "2.2.2"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'

    compile ('com.mycompany:javasdk:1.1.1')
}
```

This is the gradle file for my Android Project, again I removed the nexus server references:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mycompany.application1"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'

    compile ('com.mycompany:androidsdk:2.2.2@aar')
}
```

**NOTE:** I initially solved the issue by adding the JAR in the lib directory of the AAR project, but this is undesired. It makes having a nexus server useless. It would be good that we can just bump the JAR's version number in the AAR project's gradle file and the update happens automatically at compile time.

**NOTE2:** I tried adding `transitive=true` to my AAR dependency in the Android Project but it didn't solved anything, the real issue is that when building the AAR project, the JAR project code doesn't get bundled.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can add this task:

```
task copyLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

Dependencies will be downloaded from your Nexus, but when you need package the library, execute this task first and `jar` files will be copied and included inside final `aar`.

Comment: man, I think this is what Ive been looking for, Ill try it out and come back. Thank you!

Comment: yes, this solved the issue. I just added a `clean task` first to clear the libs directory, based from [this post](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-do-i-delete-a-subset-of-files/6855/2). After this I had to add some exclusions in the `packagingOptions` for some generated files in the `META-INF`, but in overall, this worked!

Comment: @bigdestroyer: Any idea of I can do the same thing with an aar dependency?  Here is my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41847266/how-to-package-multiple-aars-in-my-release-aar

Comment: HI @rastadrian, i have same issues, can you share your code ? about creat clean task ?

Comment: can u explain complete solution? where did you add this task?

Comment: where should I add this task in my project? I am also having the same scenerio

Comment: With this task I'm getting the error `Error:(29, 0) Could not get unknown property 'compile' for configuration container of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfigurationContainer.` I'm using Android Studio 3.0.1 and Gradle 4.1

Comment: PS: ok, I was adding in the Project Gradle and I had to add it in the Module  Gradle instead.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with gradle 3.0.1. The task executes but doesn't do nothing. It says: `:copyDeps NO-SOURCE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 0s
16:03:18: Task execution finished 'copyDeps'.`

Comment: Does this work with the `assemble` task when building only the .aar files?

Answer (score 12):

By default, AAR does not include any dependencies. Solution mentioned by @Hector should work for gradle plugin < 3.0. For Gradle plugin 3.0+, try custom config as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50186687/1069978).

```
android { ... }

// Add a new configuration to hold your dependencies
configurations {
    myConfig
}

dependencies {
    ....
    myConfig 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    myConfig 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    ...
}

task copyLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.myConfig 
    into "libs"
}
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: I copy jar lib from another module and by adding `preBuild.dependsOn copyLibs` the jar will be copied every build ( just in case the module was modiefied )

Comment: Add `afterEvaluate {assembleDebug.finalizedBy(copyLibs)}` inside `android{...}`. this will work

Answer (score 6):

None of the suggestions helped me for Gradle 4.6, so I wasted the whole day inventing my own.

Eventually I found a good Gist and modified it for my version of Gradle:
https://gist.github.com/stepio/824ef073447eb8d8d654f22d73f9f30b

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. Thanks a lot for sharing this!

Comment: This just copies the jar file to "./build/intermediates/packaged-classes/debug/libs" path. But how to merge the dependency libraries with our freshly created library?

Comment: You missed next invocations: "mergeReleaseJniLibFolders.dependsOn copyDeps" and "mergeDebugJniLibFolders.dependsOn copyDebugDeps"

Comment: I wrote this code but how to build aar file with merged jar?

Comment: Does this work with the assemble task when building only the .aar files?

Comment: @stepio It is not working for me. Could you update it for 2021 please.

Answer (score 4):

The upper ones didn't work for me in android tools 3.6.2 with Gradle. 5.6.1 . For anyone having the same issue, using https://github.com/kezong/fat-aar-android in the end worked fine for me.