# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lokhttp3/MediaType;

Tags: android, json, okhttp

Using okhttp-3.0.1.jar results in a crash:

```
 02-25 17:44:33.279: E/AndroidRuntime(30263): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 02-25 17:44:33.279: E/AndroidRuntime(30263): Process:com.littleapproom.diamondapp, PID: 30263
 02-25 17:44:33.279: E/AndroidRuntime(30263):java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution  Lokhttp3/MediaType;
 02-25 17:44:33.279: E/AndroidRuntime(30263):   at com.littleapproom.diamondapp.helper.ServiceTask.<clinit>(ServiceTask.java:68)
 02-25 17:44:33.279: E/AndroidRuntime(30263):   at com.littleapproom.diamondapp.RegisterActivity.callRegisterApi(RegisterActivity.java:74)
 02-25 17:44:33.279: E/AndroidRuntime(30263):   at com.littleapproom.diamondapp.RegisterActivity.onClick(RegisterActivity.java:50)
 02-25 17:44:33.279: E/AndroidRuntime(30263):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785)
 02-25 17:44:33.279: E/AndroidRuntime(30263):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19884)
 02-25 17:44:33.279: E/AndroidRuntime(30263):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
 02-25 17:44:33.279: E/AndroidRuntime(30263):   at  android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 02-25 17:44:33.279: E/AndroidRuntime(30263):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
 02-25 17:44:33.279: E/AndroidRuntime(30263):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
 02-25 17:44:33.279: E/AndroidRuntime(30263):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 02-25 17:44:33.279: E/AndroidRuntime(30263):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
 02-25 17:44:33.279: E/AndroidRuntime(30263):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
 02-25 17:44:33.279: E/AndroidRuntime(30263):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
 02-25 17:44:33.279: E/AndroidRuntime(30263): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "okhttp3.MediaType" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.littleapproom.diamondapp-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
 02-25 17:44:33.279: E/AndroidRuntime(30263):   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
 02-25 17:44:33.279: E/AndroidRuntime(30263):   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
 02-25 17:44:33.279: E/AndroidRuntime(30263):   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
 02-25 17:44:33.279: E/AndroidRuntime(30263):   ... 13 more
 02-25 17:44:33.279: E/AndroidRuntime(30263):   Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: okhttp3.MediaType
 02-25 17:44:33.279: E/AndroidRuntime(30263):       at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
 02-25 17:44:33.279: E/AndroidRuntime(30263):       at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
 02-25 17:44:33.279: E/AndroidRuntime(30263):       at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
 02-25 17:44:33.279: E/AndroidRuntime(30263):       at   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
 02-25 17:44:33.279: E/AndroidRuntime(30263):       ... 14 more
  02-25 17:44:33.279: E/AndroidRuntime(30263):  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

**okhttp-3.0.1.jar**
 works fine and has this missing class.
please help for solution.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Any solution? The same is happening here.

Answer (score 3):

**THIS MIGHT NOT BE AN ANSWER. I havent got sufficient Rep to comment, hence I am placing this as an answer.**

Have you imported a custom library that might be using okhttp or are you using okhttp in your project directly? I too came across this problem when I was importing a library that might have used okhttp. I have to explicitly include okhttp into my gradle to overcome this problem though I didnt use it in my code but the imported aar used it . Your case might not be the same but sharing more info on this, like your project structure and relevant code might help to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a build system issue. As mentioned [in this thread](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1266) on the OKHttp site, it seems that OkHttp3 was not included in one of the libraries used. In my case, it was an issue with the .aar I was compiling, not pulling in the library. There are a few ways to solve this, but from what I can tell, the best seems to be building to a local maven repo: [instructions are found in the S/O answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30085677/958651)

Also, just discovered was this grade command to copy the libraries to your local for building the .aar: [found on this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33539941/958651)

From other info found on the web:

> There is no automated way to package the dependencies of the library
>   inside the aar. This is contrary to proper dependency management and
>   can lead to problems down the line.
>
> If you really want to do this, you'd have to gather the dependencies
>   manually (using code in build.gradle) and manually package the files
>   in the aar.