# Gradle: how to include dependencies from repositories to output aar file

Tags: android, maven, unity-game-engine, gradle, aar

I am trying to build an arr package in Android Studio. This package contains dependecies for Zendesk:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://zendesk.artifactoryonline.com/zendesk/repo' }
    }
}

compile (group: 'com.zendesk', name: 'sdk', version: '1.7.0.1') {
    transitive = true
}

compile (group: 'com.zopim.android', name: 'sdk', version: '1.3.1.1') {
    transitive = true
}
```

I want to build this package for a Unity3d project. This package should contain all dependecies for Zendesk (the transitive = true property). When I open the aar file there is no dependencies for Zendesk. What is wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By default AARs do not include any dependencies. If you want to include them you have to copy these libs from artifactory/your cache folder into your package, either by doing it manually or this task might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33539941/4310905

Comment: That link deals with jar files. Most Android libraries will include library dependencies part of the framework that are not jar files. So that solution won't help include those.

Answer (score 7):

I know this answer comes a bit late, but still...

The `transitive` param you wrote is going to include transitive dependencies (dependencies of your dependency), which have to be set in the `pom.xml` file of the dependency you set to `compile`. So you don't really need to do that for the `aar` packaging, unless it's intended for any other purpose.

First, think that you can package an `aar` with some `jar`s inside (in the 
`libs` folder), but you cannot package an `aar` inside an `aar`.

The approach to solve your problem is:

- Get the resolved artifacts from the dependency you are interested in.
- Check which ones of the resolved artifacts are `jar` files.
- If they are `jar`, copy them to a folder and set to `compile` that folder in your `dependencies` closure.

So more or less something like this:

```
configurations {
    mypackage // create a new configuration, whose dependencies will be inspected
}

dependencies {
    mypackage 'com.zendesk:sdk:1.7.0.1' // set your dependency referenced by the mypackage configuration
    compile fileTree(dir: "${buildDir.path}/resolvedArtifacts", include: ['*.jar']) // this will compile the jar files within that folder, although the files are not there yet
}

task resolveArtifacts(type: Copy) {
    // iterate over the resolved artifacts from your 'mypackage' configuration
    configurations.mypackage.resolvedConfiguration.resolvedArtifacts.each { ResolvedArtifact resolvedArtifact ->

        // check if the resolved artifact is a jar file
        if ((resolvedArtifact.file.name.drop(resolvedArtifact.file.name.lastIndexOf('.') + 1) == 'jar')) {
            // in case it is, copy it to the folder that is set to 'compile' in your 'dependencies' closure
            from resolvedArtifact.file
            into "${buildDir.path}/resolvedArtifacts"
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can run `./gradlew clean resolveArtifacts build` and the `aar` package will have the resolved `jar`s inside.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Here is an option for Gradle 4.6: https://gist.github.com/stepio/824ef073447eb8d8d654f22d73f9f30b

Comment: @stepio i have alot of thrid party gradle dependencies and i am unable to create aar file having those libraries build with in the aar. i have used this code task copyLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.myConfig
    into 'libs'
}

Comment: @stepio aar file is generated but when i use that aar file i have to add those dependecies in my app which are required in my aar module. otherwise it gives notfound error against the source code i used from those 3rd party libs in my module

Comment: @AdeelTurk, this script worked for me, but in my cases I needed to add each library twice: first time through "copyLibs", another one - just regular "implementation". Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

**When you compile your project,** it is compiled against the necessary libraries, but **the libraries are not automatically packaged.**

What you need is called "fatjar/uberjar" and you can achieve that by [Gradle shadow plugin](http://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/).

Comment: but the res will be removed.

Comment: hi, FYI , Gradle shadow plugin can't be used to create an Android AAR 
link : https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow/issues/144