# How to publish single android AAR dependent on internal modules and 3rd party libs

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-library

### Problem statement

We need to deliver an android SDK in form of single AAR package wherein our code internally divided into various sub-modules and also has dependencies on external libs(AARs). I'm stucked in the way that how to package the modules in such a way that only single AAR is delivered which resolves the dependencies internally. Currently when the SDK code is assembled, it generates an AAR but that AAR doesn't include respective dependent modules and it hardly has a size in few KBs only.

### Solutions tried

I have already explored the way it is achieved like mavenizing the project as mentioned on:
https://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2014/05/android-guide-to-publish-aar-to-maven-gradle.html
[How to include JAR dependency into an AAR library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33445270/how-to-include-jar-dependency-into-an-aar-library)

Kindly help to get build as single AAR.

Comment: The aar doesn't contain the transitive dependencies. Publish the aar on a maven repo.In this way you will have a pom file and gradle will be able to download also the transitive dependencies

Comment: Thanks for your reply but, is there any reason why AAR doesn't include transitive dependency? 
is this android limitation or it works in this way only. In-order to publish AAR on maven, all dependent AARs need to be bundled in the mavenized form as mentioned in https://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2014/05/android-guide-to-publish-aar-to-maven-gradle.html.