# How to include JAR dependency into an AAR library gradle 3.0 above

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, android-library, aar

I have same question as in this post [How to include JAR dependency into an AAR library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33445270/how-to-include-jar-dependency-into-an-aar-library)  but only with Gradle 3.0 above. From gradle 3.0 onward, compile configurations have been replaced by api or implementation and same solution as in post above need a new solution.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved as follows:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    ...
}
```

Comment: I believe this is to refer local jar dependencies present in "libs" folder. Whereas I am looking to collect all remote dependencies to a local folder. Any suggestions there ?

Comment: You mean, you want to download the jars remotely?

Comment: Yes, wanted to download dependency jars and collect them into a folder locally inside project that I am building.