# How to share module between projects in android studio

Tags: android

I have two projects, and an common library.

- app1
- app2
- common

app1, app2 dependency on common. I want to share common library between app1 and app2, how?

I try this methods

1. export aar, and import, but common's dependencies not import
2. import gradle project in app1 and app2, but in this case, I have to keep two version code.

Comment: do you want a common part to be pre-compiled before injected in any of your apps?

Comment: @Taier in common library, there are some util java source, but dependent on third library(like rxjava)

Comment: the process of packing dependency in aar file is not trivial, you could check it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33445270/how-to-include-jar-dependency-into-an-aar-library/33539941#33539941